# Mysql mostrar suma total facturas por cliente

Tags: mysql

Estoy aprendiendo MySQL y necesito realizar una consulta para un ejercicio que me han puesto.

Son 2 tablas de una base de datos (facturas y clientes) y lo que necesito es sacar un listado de todos los clientes con su nombre y DNI y una columna más en la que muestre el total de todas sus facturas.

La consulta que he hecho es esta:

```
SELECT usuario.nombre, usuario.DNI, factura.Total_Fac 
FROM usuario LEFT JOIN factura 
ON usuario.DNI = factura.Id_Cliente 
ORDER BY usuario.nombre;
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Me muestra los resultados pero no me los suma, que es lo que necesito. Me imagino que será con sum, pero no se dónde ponerlo ni cómo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ibas mal encaminado, solo te ha faltado agrupar los resultados con un `GROUP BY`, para que de esta forma los que tienen mas de una factura no salgan varias veces, como te pasa con Javier por ejemplo. Y para que te sume los precios de las facturas meterle un `SUM()` a `Total_Fac`, de esta forma tendras la respuesta:

```sql
SELECT
    usuario.nombre,
    usuario.DNI,
    IFNULL(SUM(factura.Total_Fac), 0)
FROM
    usuario
LEFT JOIN factura ON
    usuario.DNI = factura.Id_Cliente
GROUP BY 
    usuario.DNI
ORDER BY
    usuario.nombre
```

Comment: Muchas gracias eso era lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido, ibas muy bien encaminado, solo te han faltado unos pequeños detalles. Ya que te ha funcionado, te recomiendo marcar la respuesta como aceptada con el tick y de esta forma si alguien acaba en tu pregunta podra ver como resolverla :) y si le das un voto positivo tambien se agradece mogollon :)

Comment: @adrigo Cambial `SUM()` por `IFNULL(SUM(Total_Fac,0))` para que no te dé sumas nulas, por si acaso... :)

Comment: @DavidJP, Lo proble y realmente  no da ningun problema, pero si, mejor ponerlo para prevenir. Gracias por tu aportacion, ahora lo edito.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a ejecutar:

```
select usuario.nombre, usuario.dni, sum(factura.total_fac) 
from usuario,factura 
where usuario.dni=factura.id_cliente
group by usuario.nombre,usuario.dni

union

select usuario.nombre, usuario.dni, 0 
from usuario
where usuario.dni not in (select factura.id_cliente from factura)

order by usuario.nombre
```

en el select pones las variables del cliente y la suma del total de la factura.
en el from las tablas que se van a consultar
en el where la condicion que las une, en este caso el dni del usuario con el id_cliente de la factura
luego te lo va a agrupar por dni de cliente y nombre

despues mediante el union he realizado la consulta de los cliente que no tienen factura poniendo en la columna del total un 0

espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Gracias pero el problema que me ocurre con tu consulta es que solo me muestra los clientes que tienen factura ya que hay clientes en la tabla de usuarios que no tienen ninguna factura todavia. El resultado solo muestra:
Javier 500
Victor 520
pero no muestra los demas usuarios que no tienen factura

Comment: prueba a ver con lo nuevo que te he puesto, te he puesto que te salgan los clientes sin facturas con 0 de total a ver si asi

Comment: Tranquilo, ya le he puesto yo una solucion mas sencilla, lo tuyo esta bastante lioso... y si no sabia poner un `SUM()` seguramente no entienda nada de lo que has puesto